# iOS: how to point to current control on current TableViewCell

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uitableview

I was asking the similar question last saturday, but seems like the smart folks were on barbecue party. Didn't get answer.

My problem is that I need to place UISwitch and two UIButtons on UITableViewCell and when the UISwitch will change state these UIButtons should appear or disappear. These cells are do not for navigation to anywhere and thus I use them only for informational presentation, and do not use

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

[image]

In - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath methos I've created the required controls programmatically and assigned to each of them tag value and action:@selector.

Now in other methods I managed how to get the itemID from current row. Like in this method:

```
-(void)setItem:(UISwitch*)sender
{
int n;
UITableViewCell *cell;
if(sender.tag==9001)
{
    cell=((UITableViewCell*)[sender superview]);
    n=([self.tableView indexPathForCell:cell].row);
}
item=[self.arr objectAtIndex:n];

NSDate *today=[NSDate date];
NSDateFormatter *formatter =[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[formatter setDateStyle:NSDateFormatterMediumStyle];
NSString *now =[formatter stringFromDate:today];

if(sender.on)
{
    DBAccess *access=[[DBAccess alloc]init];
    [access setItemON:item.itemID date:now];
    //qualityBtn.hidden=NO;
    [qualityBtn setTitleColor:[UIColor blackColor] forState:normal];
    [qualityBtn setTitle:@"UNDEF" forState:normal];
}
else 
{
    DBAccess *access=[[DBAccess alloc]init];
    [access setItemOFF:item.itemID];
}
}
```

So, my problem is when this method works, the qualityBtn:s on other cells also getting title etc, but I need that the current button on current control will change due the method's logic. So, how to point in method that it will change only the controls placed on current cell and will omit others.

Thank you in advance.

EDIT:

@property(nonatomic,strong)UIButton *qualityBtn;
 yes, it's global.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
item=[self.arr objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];

static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
ItemCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];


self.switchView = [[UISwitch alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(7, 8, 79, 27)];
[switchView addTarget:self action:@selector(setItem:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
[switchView setTag:9001];


qualityBtn=[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
[qualityBtn addTarget:self 
               action:@selector(setQuality:)
 forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];

qualityBtn.frame = CGRectMake(236, 8, 72, 21);
qualityBtn.titleLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:12];
[qualityBtn setTag:9002];

itemMemoBtn=[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[itemMemoBtn addTarget:self 
                action:@selector(setItemMemo:)
      forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
itemMemoBtn.frame = CGRectMake(274, 43, 34, 30);
[itemMemoBtn setTag:9003];
[itemMemoBtn setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"comment-icon"] forState:normal];

lblDate=[[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(14, 34, 72, 21)];
lblDate.font=[UIFont systemFontOfSize:9];
[lblDate setTag:9003];

[cell addSubview:switchView];
[cell addSubview:qualityBtn];
[cell addSubview:itemMemoBtn];
[cell addSubview:lblDate];
[cell setIndentationWidth:45];
[cell setIndentationLevel:1];

lblDate.text=item.date;
cell.lblKM.text=item.kmRef;
cell.lblInfo.text=item.info;
if(item.dateFrom.length>0 && item.dateUntil.length>0)
{
    cell.lblYears.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ - %@",item.dateFrom,item.dateUntil];
}
if(item.dateUntil.length<1)
{
    cell.lblYears.text=item.dateFrom;
}

if(item.mintMark.length<1)
{
    //cell.mintmarksImageView.hidden=YES;
}
cell.lblMintmarks.text=item.mintMark;

if(item.memo.length>0)
{
    cell.lblMemoStatus.text=@"YES";
}
else 
{
    cell.lblMemoStatus.text=@"NO";
}

cell.lblRarity.text=item.rarity;

if(item.isAvailable==0)
{ 
    [switchView setOn:NO];
    //qualityBtn.hidden=YES;
    //lblDate.hidden=YES;
    qualityBtn.titleLabel.text=@"UNDEF";
}
else {
    [switchView setOn:YES];
   // lblDate.hidden=NO;
    NSString *quality=nil;
    switch(item.quality)
    {
        case 1:
        {
            quality=@"UNDEF";
            break;
        }
        case 2:
        {
            quality=@"G";
            break;
        }
        case 3:
        {
            quality=@"VG";
            break;
        }
        case 4:
        {
            quality=@"F";
            break;
        }
        case 5:
        {
            quality=@"VF";
            break;
        }
        case 6:
        {
            quality=@"XF";
            break;
        }
        case 7:
        {
            quality=@"UNC";
            break;
        }
        case 8:
        {
            quality=@"PROOF";
            break;
        }
    }
    [qualityBtn setTitleColor:[UIColor blackColor] forState:normal];
    [qualityBtn setTitle:quality forState:normal];
}

return cell;
}
```

Comment: Can you show the code, where you actually assign qualityBtn? From your provided snippet it seems like it is some kind of global object, not related to the current cell.

Comment: In your cellForRowAtIndexPath you do the following:

qualityBtn=[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];

So qualityBtn is a global variable? I'd suggest to write a custom UITableViewCell subclass, and contain those objects inside the class. I'll write an answer

Comment: I have such class. Some objects living there and some in items class. these that will not be changed due the logic living in cell class and changeable in items class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest that you extend your UITableViewCell subclass and have properties for your switch and buttons. Something like this:

```
@interface YourCustomCell: UITableViewCell
@property(strong,nonatomic) UISwitch *switchView
@property(strong,nonatomic) UIBtton *qualityBtn
@property(strong,nonatomic) UIBtton *memoBtn
@end
```

In cellForRowAtIndexPath: you would then do something like this:

```
cell.switchView = [[UISwitch alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(7, 8, 79, 27)];
[cell.switchView addTarget:self action:@selector(setItem:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
[cell.switchView setTag:9001];
/* setting the other properties is not shown */
```

Now in your setItem: method you can simple access the correct buttons by doing

```
cell.qualityBtn
cell.memoBtn
```

But remember that you should update some kind of model, which keeps track of the switch states so that when a user scrolls the table and the cells get deallocated and reallocated the cells are allocated with their correct state (buttons being show or not). Simplest would be an NSDictionary, which has the NSIndexPath of the cell as key.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Sounds promising. I'll try it now.

Comment: Does it mean I have to set the controls on cell and use IBOutlets?

Comment: If you want to build your view in IB, then you have to mark the properties as IBOutlets, yes. And you have to connect them in your XIB-File/Storyboard.

Comment: Dammit... first of all I'm pointing to wrong class. In setItem I probably should point to ItemCell and not to TableViewCell class...

Comment: That might be a good idea, if you want the IDE not to complain about you accessing properties that aren't part of the class. Also in IB you want to point to the correct class, in order to hook up your outlets :)

Comment: If I try to cell.switchView = [[UISwitch alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(7, 8, 79, 27)]; in items class it doesn't effect the control.

Comment: What is your "items" class? Are you referring to the UITableViewCell subclass?

Comment: All right. There were other issues. it works. thank you Johannes.

Answer (score 2):

Don't add subviews to the cell in the delegate method. You have to subclass the UITableViewCell (for ex.: MCMyCustomTableViewCell, create your elements in it so it will be reusable (through the dequeue method). When done, create a variable with property in the cell (for example @property (nonatomic, strong) NSInteger cellIndex;) which you'll have to fill in when doing your cellForRowAtIndexPath: ... add targets to your buttons in the controller and when status changes or the button is pressed do:

```
- (void)didClickButton:(UIButton *)sender{
    NSInteger index = [(MCMyCustomTableViewCell *)sender.superview cellIndex];
    // Place for your code here
}
```

and than the same with the switch :)

Comment: So, do you mean that I can place my switch on the cell in storyboard and use operate with it from items class?

Comment: To be honest I don't use story boards nor NIX (XIB) files and do everything in the code as when you have multiple developers on the project it is much easier to manage the code base ...

Comment: first take a look at my tutorial here: http://www.xprogress.com/post-32-uinavigationbar-tutorial-with-uitable-pushing-detail-view-using-didselectrowatindexpath-and-all-xcode-example-source-files/ That will give you an idea how to do tables programatically. Even if you'll be using story boards in the future, it will be pretty handy to know how it works :)

Comment: the tutorial doesn't have the inner elements but when you done with it, I am sure the comment above will be much clearer to you.

Comment: I can do it as well. it's just real pain to play with CGRect.

Comment: Thank you Ondrej! I've bookmarked you tutorial. Will investigate it later tonight.